# How to create calculated column from mysql table row data

Tags: mysql

I have table like below.

```
id created_at grand_total amount_due
```

i would like to display amount in `tendays`column with calculating from existing data.

```
    if(SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),created_at)) >=0 and SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),created_at) <= 10
then
grand_total - amount_due as tendays
```

how would this be possible.

Comment: Where do the dates in `DATEDIFF()` come from?

Comment: first date will be now and second will be created_at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) or the [IF() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if). You can also use a BETWEEN condition to avoid code duplication. I would write the query as following:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    created_at,
    grand_total,
    amount_due,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(),created_at) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
        THEN grand_total - amount_due
        ELSE NULL
    END as tendays
FROM some_table;
```

Note that you need to define a value for the case that the condition isn't met in the ELSE clause. However, if it's NULL (like in my example) you can also omit the ELSE clause since NULL is the default "value".

Using IF() it might be:

```
IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(),created_at) BETWEEN 0 AND 10, grand_total - amount_due, NULL) as tendays
```